# Can we change the Size of text which is written in values of putextra and assigned in next activity of textview?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-intent, text-size

I am working on a project in which, I am exporting string value from one activity to 2nd activity but I just can't resize that string value which is assigned inside `TextView` in second activity.

Code of 1st activity:

```
  if (modelList.get(position).getJtitle().equals("Hello World"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,CodeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle","Hello World");
                intent.putExtra("contentTv","Class HelloWorld\n" +
                        "{\n" +
                        "public static void main(String args[])\n" +
                        "{\n" +
                        "System.out.println(\"Welcome to Hello World Program\");\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "}");
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

2nd activity code :

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jcode);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    TextView codetv = findViewById(R.id.jtextview);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mActionBarTitle = intent.getStringExtra("actionBarTitle");
    String mContent = intent.getStringExtra("contentTv");
    actionBar.setTitle(mActionBarTitle);
    codetv.setText(mContent);
}
```

The output looks like this, how can we change that textSize:
[image: Output example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_jcode);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

TextView codetv = findViewById(R.id.jtextview);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String mActionBarTitle = intent.getStringExtra("actionBarTitle");
String mContent = intent.getStringExtra("contentTv");
actionBar.setTitle(mActionBarTitle);
codetv.setText(mContent);
codetv.setTextSize(10); //Replace 10 with whatever size you want. 

}
```

Comment: Still not working, that default size remains constant

Comment: I notice that the text in the screenshot of the emulator is different from the string you are supplying with the intent. Are you sure you are looking at the correct activity?

Comment: Well you must be leaving out some important details as other wise `codetv.setTextSize(10);` would work. Post all your code from the 2nd activity

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try setting TextSize programmatically to `codetv`

Or set textSize of TextView statically in .xml layout

Comment: I tried it but it's didn't working, can u suggest some another method